# 認識ワードのビジュアルプログラミングでの検知方法

Tags: aibo-developer, aibo-visual-programming

aiboビジュアルプログラミングで、自分が登録した認識ワードを検知するようにしたいと考えていますが、うまくいきません。
[公式ドキュメント　認識ワードの登録方法](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%98%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

上記のドキュメントに従って、
①開発者設定でアクセストークンを取得【済】で、有効期限内である状態とする。
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/settings/token
②認識ワードで「音声コマンド」の「usercommand1」に、「あいうえお」という認識ワードを登録。
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/settings/keyword

この状態で、ビジュアルプログラミングのほうで、
③"変数" の "変数を作る" で、登録した音声コマンドを設定・・・とあるので、変数「usercommand1」を設定。
　※「あいうえお」ではなく「usercommand1」とした
④「aiboがおはようといわれたとき」の「おはよう」部分を変数「usercommand1」に変更

としたのですが、これで認識しません。
おはように戻すと、ちゃんと認識します。

※イベント通知画面　https://developer.aibo.com/jp/settings/event　でも
　念のため、「voice_command::usercommand1」に「あいうえお」が追加されている状態にもしています。
　こちらを消してもダメでした。
※イベント通知画面　でのエンドポイントは設定していません。

ドキュメント通りかと思いますが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aiboビジュアルプログラミングで登録した認識ワードを検知したい場合は、
"aiboが「変数」といわれたとき"に入れる「変数」の、名前ではなく、
「変数」の値を音声コマンドのいずれか（例えば usercommand1）に設定する必要があります。
変数「usercommand1」を使う場合だと、「変数」カテゴリにある "「変数」を「0」にする" のブロックを、
"「usercommand1」を「usercommand1」にする" として実行し、変数の値を変更してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
下記の公式ドキュメントの該当部分について、現状、ご回答の下の「言われたとき」しか画像がないので、上の「usercommand1をusercommand1にする」の初期設定画像も追加して頂けるとありがたいです。
aiboプログラミング部、全員解決できませんでした^^;

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%98%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D